# jQuery filter a list using multiple select boxes

Tags: jquery, list, filter

I need to be able to filer a long list on the client side using multiple select boxes.

I have managed to do this successfully using one select box.

```
<select id="company">
  <option selected="true" >ALL</option>
  <option>GM</option>
  <option>Honda</option>
  <option>Ford</option>
</select>

<select id="company2">
  <option selected="true" >ALL</option>
  <option>Buick [GM]</option>
  <option>Honda</option>
  <option>Ford</option>
</select>

<ul id="names" multiple="multiple" size="8">
  <li>Chevy [GM]</li>
  <li>Buick [GM]</li>
  <li>Civic [Honda]</li>
  <li>Accord [Honda]</li>
  <li>Focus [Ford]</li>
</ul>
```

And the script

```
 var names = $('#names li').clone();

$('#company').change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();  
  $('#names').empty();
  names.filter(function(idx, el) {
    return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf( val ) >= 0;
}).appendTo('#names');

  $('#company2').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();  
    $('#names').empty();
    names.filter(function(idx, el) {
    return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf(val) >= 0;
  }).appendTo('#names');
  });
});
```

This nearly works, I can select GM in the first select box and the list will change the `<li>` to

- Chevy [GM]
- Buick [GM]

If I then use the second select box to select `Buick [GM]` the `<li>` will change to just display

- Buick [GM]

Which is what I want. However I have found if the second box selects Honda it will display

- Civic [Honda]
- Accord [Honda]

My question is how can I chain the two together so it will use both GM and Honda together?

The list with out any filters is:

- Chevy [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Civic [Honda]
- Accord [Honda]
- Focus [Ford]

​When we select GM from the first filter it displays

- Chevy [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]

so if we select 'Buick [GM]' form the second filter the list now displays

- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]
- Buick [GM]

which is correct, but the second filter is set to Ford the list will display

- Focus [Ford]

so the filters are not working together  ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I don't really understand what your after. Could you explain in more detail?

Answer (score 1):

You should combine the event handler for both `select` elements:

```
var $names = $('#names'),
    $namesAll = $names.find('li'),
    $company1 = $('#company'),
    $company2 = $('#company2');

$company1.add( $company2 ).change(function() {

    var val1 = $company1.val(),
        val2 = $company2.val();

    $names.empty();

    if ( val1 == 'ALL' && val2 == 'ALL' ) {
        $names.append( $namesAll );
    }
    else {
        $namesAll.filter(function(i, el) {
            var $el = $(el);
            return ~$el.text().indexOf( val1 ) || ~$el.text().indexOf( val2 );
        }).appendTo( $names );
    }
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EfEYQ/

---

The above solution works, but I'd advise you not to mess with the DOM so much. Instead, you should have a `hidden` class in your CSS, then just toggle that class on the `li`s you want to show:

```
var  $names = $('#names li'),
     $company1 = $('#company'),
     $company2 = $('#company2');

$company1.add( $company2 ).change(function() {

    var val1 = $company1.val(),
        val2 = $company2.val();

    if ( val1 == 'ALL' && val2 == 'ALL' ) {
        $names.removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else {
        $names.addClass('hidden').filter(function(i, el) {
            var $el = $(el);
            return ~$el.text().indexOf( val1 ) || ~$el.text().indexOf( val2 );
        }).removeClass('hidden');
    }
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/89qbV/

---

After further clarification in the comments, I think this might be what you're looking for:

```
var  $names = $('#names li'),
     $company1 = $('#company'),
     $company2 = $('#company2');

$company1.add( $company2 ).change(function() {

    var val1 = $company1.val(),
        val2 = $company2.val();

    if ( val1 == 'ALL' && val2 == 'ALL' ) {
        $names.removeClass('hidden');
    }
    else {
        $names.addClass('hidden').filter(function(i, el) {

            var $el = $(el),
                include = true;

            if ( val1 != 'ALL' && !~$el.text().indexOf( val1 ) ) include = false;
            if ( val2 != 'ALL' && !~$el.text().indexOf( val2 ) ) include = false;

            return include;

        }).removeClass('hidden');
    }
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WfNav/

Comment: That's great I should of really posted the fidle instead off all the code. However your solution lets me still select honda after selecting GM.

Comment: @JasonBruce - Isn't that what you want?

Comment: No, I should only be able to filter the results down further i.e after GM is selected and Honda is selected after GM then the list should not update. It should only update if an option shown in the new list is selected

Comment: @JasonBruce - I'm not sure I fully understand you, but I added some code to the answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: That's it thank you! Sorry for not explaining my self correctly

Comment: hello, could you please check this question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54246790/wherebetween-and-all-filters-in-one-form I am having the nearly same issue.. but stuck how to fix it... @JosephSilber

Comment: Is there a way I can add 3rd select dropdown filter?

Answer (score 0):

I approached this using your previous code, I wasn't sure though of the behaviour of the 'ALL's so I only have the first select element taking priority (if first is all, all are shown). If you want you can just add to the filterNames() || val2 === 'ALL'

Also, in your code I noticed that the change event on the second select element isn't hooked until the first element is changed. So there was that.

Hope this helps!

```
var names = $('#names li').clone();

$('#company').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    var val2 = $('#company2').val();
    filterNames(val, val2);
});

$('#company2').change(function() {
    var val = $('#company').val();
    var val2 = $(this).val();
    filterNames(val, val2);
});

function filterNames(val, val2) {
    $('#names').empty();
    names.filter(function(idx, el) {
        return val === 'ALL' || $(el).text().indexOf( val ) >= 0 || $(el).text().indexOf( val2 ) >= 0;
    }).appendTo('#names');
}
```